# Why this won't get value to None?

Tags: python, mysql

I have problem with my python code where code should get value to pelaaja.nimi, pelaaja.joukkoe, pelaaja.pelipaikka.

file 1 (db.py)

```
def luo_turnaus(row):
     return Turnaus(row["pelaajaid"], row["pelipaikkaid"], row["pelipaikka"], row["joukkoeid"], row["joukkoe"], row["nimi"])

def hae_pelaajat():
    query1 = "SELECT pelaaja.*, joukkoe.joukkoe, pelipaikka.pelipaikka FROM pelaaja "
    query2 = "INNER JOIN joukkoe ON pelaaja.joukkoeid = joukkoe.joukkoeid "
    query3 = "INNER JOIN pelipaikka ON pelaaja.pelipaikkaid = pelipaikka.pelipaikkaid"
    query = query1 + query2 + query3
    with closing(mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)) as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        tulokset = cursor.fetchall()

    pelaajat = []
    for row in tulokset:
        pelaajat.append(luo_turnaus(row))
    
    return pelaajat
```

file 2 (oliot.py)

```
class Turnaus:
    #alustus
    def __init__(self, pelaajaid=0, peliid=0, peli=None, joukkoeid=0, joukkoe=None, tehdytmaalit=0, paastetytmaalit=0, nimi=None, pelipaikkaid=0, pelipaikka=None):
     self.peliid = peliid
     self.peli = peli
     self.joukkoeid = joukkoeid
     self.joukkoe = joukkoe
     self.tehdytmaalit = tehdytmaalit
     self.paastetytmaalit = paastetytmaalit
     self.nimi = nimi
     self.pelipaikkaid = pelipaikkaid
     self.pelipaikka = pelipaikka
     self.pelaajaid = pelaajaid
```

file 3 (ui.py)

```
def katso_pelaajat():
    print("")
    print("Kaikki pelaajat")
    print("-" * 150)
    line_format = "{:<5} {:<20} {:<15} {:<15}"
    print(line_format.format("ID", "Nimi", "Joukkoe", "Pelipaikka"))
    print("-" * 150)
    pelaajat = db.hae_pelaajat()
    for pelaaja in pelaajat:
        print(line_format.format(str(pelaaja.pelaajaid), pelaaja.nimi, pelaaja.joukkoe, pelaaja.pelipaikka))
        print("-" * 150)
```

I can't count anymore how many different ways I have tried and it should print column where is ID, Name, Team and gamespot.

Code prints TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.**format**

Comment: What is `luo_turnaus(row)`? Is that supposed to be `Turnaus(row)`? If you want each column to be an argument you have to write `Turnaus(*row)`

Comment: It's should be function to use class `Turnaus(row)` or thats what I have learned in my 
school class. I'm just learning and most parts is done by example that are shown to me. Sorry if there is some problems to understand.

Comment: You're calling the constructor of `Turnaus` with positional arguments, not keyword arguments. So `self.nimi` would be populated with the 8th arg, but you only pass 6 args.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the definition at the top.

Comment: Perhaps you intend: `return Turnaus(pelaajaid=row["pelaajaid"], pelipaikkaid=row["pelipaikkaid"] ... `